# Cups-2.2.5 web page display stopped "Filter failed"

Tags: linux, printing, filter, cups

I have built Cups-2.2.5, also built cups-filter-1.17.8 and all its dependency.

My platform info:
mips-linux

When i try to "Print Test Page" on web page, it prompt "stopped Filter failed". Then i check the log file(/var/log/cups/error_log), info as below:

```html
================ ============
emote-canceled,cups-remote-aborted,cups-remote-completed"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetPrinterReasons(p=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series),s="-cups-missing-filter-warning,cups-insecure-filter-warning"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdCreateProfile(job_id=3, allow_networking=0) = NULL
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdCreateProfile(job_id=3, allow_networking=1) = NULL
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdContinueJob(job=0x773d85b8(3)): current_file=0, num_files=1
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] 4 filters for job:
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] bannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] pdftoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 66)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] rastertohp (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/HP_Deskjet_5520_series, cost 50)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] job-sheets=none,none
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[0]="HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[1]="3"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[2]="admin"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[3]="Test Page"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[4]="1"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] argv[6]="/usr/local/var/spool/cups/d00003-001"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/usr/local/var/cache/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/local/share/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/local/share/doc/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/local/share/cups/fonts"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/usr/local/var/spool/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/local/lib/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/usr/local/etc/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/usr/local/var/run/cups"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[8]="HOME=/usr/local/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/local/lib/cups/filter:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@(none)"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.5"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/usr/local/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/usr/local/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[19]="LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[20]="PPD=/usr/local/etc/cups/ppd/HP_Deskjet_5520_series.ppd"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://HP/Deskjet%205520%20series?serial=CN36A1665W05SW"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=HP Deskjet 5520 series"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[26]="PRINTER=HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: File \"/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf\" permissions OK (040755/uid=0/gid=0).
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Preparing to start "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf", arguments:
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[0] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/daemon/cups-exec"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[1] = "-g"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[2] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[3] = "-n"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[4] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[5] = "-u"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[6] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[7] = "none"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[8] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[9] = "HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[10] = "3"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[11] = "admin"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[12] = "Test Page"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[13] = "1"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[14] = "job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[15] = "/usr/local/var/spool/cups/d00003-001"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting spawn attributes.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting file actions.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Calling posix_spawn.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: pid=5022
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess(command="/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf", argv=0x7f959f10, envp=0x7f95bf80, infd=-1, outfd=24, errfd=18, backfd=19, sidefd=21, root=0, profile=(nil), job=0x773d85b8(3), pid=0x773d8664) = 5022
I [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 5022)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: File \"/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf\" permissions OK (040755/uid=0/gid=0).
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Preparing to start "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf", arguments:
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[0] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/daemon/cups-exec"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[1] = "-g"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[2] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[3] = "-n"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[4] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[5] = "-u"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[6] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[7] = "none"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[8] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[9] = "HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[10] = "3"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[11] = "admin"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[12] = "Test Page"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[13] = "1"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[14] = "job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting spawn attributes.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting file actions.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Calling posix_spawn.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: pid=5023
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess(command="/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf", argv=0x7f959f10, envp=0x7f95bf80, infd=23, outfd=26, errfd=18, backfd=19, sidefd=21, root=0, profile=(nil), job=0x773d85b8(3), pid=0x773d8668) = 5023
I [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 5023)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: File \"/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster\" permissions OK (040755/uid=0/gid=0).
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Preparing to start "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster", arguments:
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[0] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/daemon/cups-exec"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[1] = "-g"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[2] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[3] = "-n"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[4] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[5] = "-u"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[6] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[7] = "none"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[8] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[9] = "HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[10] = "3"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[11] = "admin"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[12] = "Test Page"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[13] = "1"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[14] = "job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting spawn attributes.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting file actions.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Calling posix_spawn.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: pid=5024
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess(command="/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster", argv=0x7f959f10, envp=0x7f95bf80, infd=25, outfd=24, errfd=18, backfd=19, sidefd=21, root=0, profile=(nil), job=0x773d85b8(3), pid=0x773d866c) = 5024
I [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster (PID 5024)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: File \"/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp\" permissions OK (040755/uid=0/gid=0).
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Preparing to start "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp", arguments:
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[0] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/daemon/cups-exec"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[1] = "-g"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[2] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[3] = "-n"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[4] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[5] = "-u"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[6] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[7] = "none"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[8] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[9] = "HP_Deskjet_5520_series"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[10] = "3"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[11] = "admin"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[12] = "Test Page"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[13] = "1"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[14] = "job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting spawn attributes.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting file actions.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Calling posix_spawn.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: pid=5025
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess(command="/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp", argv=0x7f959f10, envp=0x7f95bf80, infd=23, outfd=26, errfd=18, backfd=19, sidefd=21, root=0, profile=(nil), job=0x773d85b8(3), pid=0x773d8670) = 5025
I [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp (PID 5025)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: File \"/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb\" permissions OK (040755/uid=0/gid=0).
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Preparing to start "/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb", arguments:
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[0] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/daemon/cups-exec"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[1] = "-g"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[2] = "65534"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[3] = "-n"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[4] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[5] = "-u"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[6] = "0"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[7] = "none"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[8] = "/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[9] = "usb://HP/Deskjet%205520%20series?serial=CN36A1665W05SW"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[10] = "3"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[11] = "admin"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[12] = "Test Page"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[13] = "1"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: argv[14] = "job-uuid=urn:uuid:e16df11e-3eec-320e-40ef-cf3098d27489 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=2075 time-at-processing=2075"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting spawn attributes.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Setting file actions.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: Calling posix_spawn.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess: pid=5026
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdStartProcess(command="/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb", argv=0x7f959f10, envp=0x7f95bf80, infd=25, outfd=-1, errfd=18, backfd=20, sidefd=22, root=1, profile=(nil), job=0x773d85b8(3), pid=0x773d86b8) = 5026
I [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Started backend /usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 5026)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=17, read_cb=0x7735b9c4, write_cb=(nil), data=0x773d85b8)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=job-state-changed, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=0x773d85b8(3), text="Job #%d started.", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused job-state-changed event...
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] Returning IPP successful-ok for Print-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/HP_Deskjet_5520_series) from localhost
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] Content-Length: 191
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] cupsdSendHeader: code=200, type="application/ipp", auth_type=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=11, read_cb=0x773412d0, write_cb=0x77340784, data=0x77410440)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] process_children()
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=5022, name=0x7f96bae0, namelen=1024, job_id=0x7f96bf80(3)) = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] PID 5022 (/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) stopped with status 127 (File too large)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] con->http=0x774115b0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=191, response=0x773d84b8(IPP_STATE_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=IPP_STATE_DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=191
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] Flushing write buffer.
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] New state is HTTP_STATE_WAITING
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=11, read_cb=0x773412d0, write_cb=(nil), data=0x77410440)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Client 7] Waiting for request.
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: error while loading shared libraries: liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: error while loading shared libraries: liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] process_children()
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=5024, name=0x7f96bae0, namelen=1024, job_id=0x7f96bf80(3)) = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] PID 5024 (/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster) stopped with status 127 (File too large)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetIPPVars(response=0x77c0d060, filter_name=\"(null)\", filter_value=\"(null)\", prefix=\"(null)\", parent_el=0)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SERVER_NAME=\"192.168.0.1\"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REMOTE_USER=\"admin\"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: CUPS_VERSION=\"CUPS v2.2.5\"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetIPPObjectVars(obj=0x77c0d0e8, prefix=\"(null)\", element=0)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SERVER_NAME=\"192.168.0.1\"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REMOTE_USER=\"admin\"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: CUPS_VERSION=\"CUPS v2.2.5\"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] HP_Deskjet_5520_series: error while loading shared libraries: liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] process_children()
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=5023, name=0x7f96bae0, namelen=1024, job_id=0x7f96bf80(3)) = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] PID 5023 (/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) stopped with status 127 (File too large)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout(-1): 31 seconds to write dirty config/state files
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] STATE: +connecting-to-device
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetPrinterReasons(p=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series),s="+connecting-to-device"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=printer-state-changed, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=(nil)(0), text="Printer \"%s\" state changed.", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Printer using device file \"/dev/usb/lp0\"...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] STATE: -connecting-to-device
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetPrinterReasons(p=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series),s="-connecting-to-device"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=printer-state-changed, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=(nil)(0), text="Printer \"%s\" state changed.", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] backendRunLoop(print_fd=0, device_fd=5, snmp_fd=-1, addr=(nil), use_bc=1, side_cb=0x770c9af0)
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
E [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] No pages were found.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=job-progress, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=0x773d85b8(3), text="%s", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused job-progress event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=printer-state-changed, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=(nil)(0), text="Printer \"%s\" state changed.", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Read 4 bytes of print data...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] process_children()
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=5025, name=0x7f96bae0, namelen=1024, job_id=0x7f96bf80(3)) = "/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] PID 5025 (/usr/local/lib/cups/filter/rastertohp) stopped with status 1.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout(-1): 31 seconds to write dirty config/state files
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] STATE: -media-empty-warning
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetPrinterReasons(p=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series),s="-media-empty-warning"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] STATE: -offline-report
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdSetPrinterReasons(p=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series),s="-offline-report"
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] The printer is now connected.
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] Wrote 4 bytes of print data...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=job-progress, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=0x773d85b8(3), text="%s", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused job-progress event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdAddEvent(event=printer-state-changed, dest=0x773c87d0(HP_Deskjet_5520_series), job=(nil)(0), text="Printer \"%s\" state changed.", ...)
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] process_children()
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=5026, name=0x7f96bae0, namelen=1024, job_id=0x7f96bf80(3)) = "/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb"
D [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] [Job 3] PID 5026 (/usr/local/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=0
d [01/Jan/1970:00:34:35 +0000] finalize_job(job=0x773d85b8(3))
=============================
```

I can see info "error while loading shared libraries: liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". However, this library "liblcms2.so.2" is exist in search directory:

```html
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# find / -name liblcms2.so.2
/mnt/apps/lib/liblcms2.so.2
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# ls -l /mnt/apps/lib/liblcms2.so.2*
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            17 Dec 11  2017 /mnt/apps/lib/liblcms2.so.2 -> liblcms2.so.2.0.8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        377952 Dec 12  2017 /mnt/apps/lib/liblcms2.so.2.0.8
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# cd /usr
[3384:RG]# pwd
/usr
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 10  2017 local -> /mnt/apps
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH             
/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/public:/usr/local/lib/private:/usr/local/lib/gpl:/lib
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]# 
[3384:RG]#
```

Now, i really don't know how to find this issue reason...

Any idea?

Thanks, 
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

Method:
When i compile cups-filter, i specify arguments "-Wl,--rpath=lib_path_in_run_board" in flag:CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, CPPFLAGS. Why need specify three flags? I must ensure the lib_path_in_run_board compiled into the execute program.

There is another issue confuse me. liblcms2.so.2 exist in search directory in evironment virable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. And i use LD_DEBUG=libs execute_program to debug can see it will search the directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and found specify libs. Why execute actually will report "error while loading shared libraries: liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I really don't  understand .

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue today.

My printer is LENOVO_M2041_F2072_Series

what i found in the error_log indicates that there is something wrong with file permission.

because i saw lots of permission deny error in the log.

here is part of my log

> D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] Started filter /Library/Printers/LENOVO/M2041_F2072/prefilter (PID 80309)
>   D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] Started filter /usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgpdftoraster (PID 80310)
>   D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] Started filter /Library/Printers/LENOVO/M2041_F2072/rastertolenovo (PID 80311)
>   D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] Started backend /usr/libexec/cups/backend/usb (PID 80312)
>   D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] execv failed: Permission denied
>   D [15/Dec/2018:21:08:28 +0800] [Job 36] execv failed: Permission denied

I realized that some thing is wrong with the permission of `/Library/Printers/LENOVO/M2041_F2072/prefilter` or `/Library/Printers/LENOVO/M2041_F2072/rastertolenovo`

so i switched to super user using

`sudo su`

and changed their permission
`sh-3.2# chmod +x prefilter rastertolenovo`

Then I clicked print again, IT WORKS!